# Why should I subscribe on the main thread?

Tags: android, rx-java

trying to figure out some thing from this resource: https://www.raywenderlich.com/384-reactive-programming-with-rxandroid-in-kotlin-an-introduction

I am stuck with a question: why should I call subscribeOn() in the main thread instead of Schedulers.io()?

When I do subscription like that my app is freezing on a couple secongs and I am dropping frames.

```
searchTextObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map { cheeseSearchEngine.search(it) }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe {
                    showResult(it)
                }
```

[image: Dropping frames screen]

And then I am subscribing in the main thread and observe it in Schedulers.io() (I am also don't understood why should I do it like that) app is not freezing at all.

```
searchTextObservable
                .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .map { cheeseSearchEngine.search(it) }
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe {
                    showResult(it)
                }
```

Can anybody please explain why is it working like that ?

**EDIT**

```
// 1
private fun createTextChangeObservable(): Observable<String> {
  // 2
  val textChangeObservable = Observable.create<String> { emitter ->
    // 3
    val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {

      override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) = Unit

      override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) = Unit

      // 4
      override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        s?.toString()?.let { emitter.onNext(it) }
      }

    }

    // 5
    queryEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)

    // 6
    emitter.setCancellable {
      queryEditText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
    }
  }

  // 7
  return textChangeObservable
}
```

Comment: You do not need to do long running calculation on Main Thread!
You should only use `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` when you want to do something with UI!
otherwise you can always use `Schedulers.io()`

Comment: Could you please provide the code for searchTextObservable?

Comment: @HansWurst, I've provided it. Please find it under edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subscribeOn vs. observeOn

subscribeOn will call create method of Observable on given Scheduler. It does not matter how many times you use subscribeOn. The first subscribeOn to source-observable (first in chain) always wins.

observeOn will switch thread from operator to operator. When upstream emits a value on Thread X it will be switched over to Thread Y from given Scheduler in observeOn-Operator. Everything below observeOn will be processed in Thread Y now.

Best guess on provided example 1:
Using subscribeOn will call Observable#create on Schedulers#io. Everything in the create-lambda will be called on this thread from Schedulers#io. The listener-callback (onTextChanged) can actually happen on another thread. In this case it is the UI-Thread, because it is some kind of UI element. Now onNext will be called from UI-Thread (emitter.onNext(it)). The value will be emitted to #map operator on UI-Thread (.map { cheeseSearchEngine.search(it) }) and cheeseSearchEngine#search will block the UI-Thread.

Example2:
Uses as first operator ".subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())". This has actually no effect, because you are already in the UI-Thread. In this case the create-lambda will be called from AndroidSchedulers#mainThread. The onNext will be emitted on the UI-Thread as-well, just in Example1, because the UI triggers the onTextChanged-Event. The value will then be put through observeOn(Schedulers.io()). Everything from the observeOn-point will be executed on an Schedulers#io-Thread. This will in turn not block the ui, when map does some HTTP-request (or some sort of long running IO). After map is finished and emits the next value downstreams the next observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) will switch back to the UI-Thread. Therefore you can now saftly change the UI in the subscribe-lambda, because you are on the UI-Thread.
As a conclusion the first subscribeOn in Example2 can be omitted, if it does not matter from which Thread the listener-registration is happening (listener-reg must probably be thread-safe).

Summary:
Using subscribeOn will only invoke the create lambda on given Scheduler-Thread. The callback from registered listener in create may happen on another Thread.
This is why Example1 will block the UI-Thread and Example2 will not.

Comment: Thanks for such explanation!

Answer (score 1):

This is the beauty of Rx. Easy thread switching. Basically in Rx we can switch between different threads just by calling subscribeOn() or ObserveOn(). The difference between these two is, when subscribeOn(Thread1) is called, the task (in your example - cheeseSearchEngine.search(it)) runs on Thread1.

However, when you call observeOn(Thread2), the result of the task performed is give to Thread2. It means the result will be worked on Thread2. (In your example showResult will be called on Thread2)

So when you call subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()), the task is done on IO thread. Once the result is ready it will be given to Main UI thread on calling observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).

When done vice-versa, you are basically trying to do the task on UI thread rather using IO background thread. With this approach if you try to update any UI element, an exception will be thrown saying "UI elements can't be accessed from background thread (CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views)".

Hope I answer your question. Happy coding in Rx.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still I din't get it. As I understand - I should call the subscribeOn() where I am doing all calculations using IO thread. And then represent the result on UI thread using observeOn(UI thread). But in this example I am dropping frames If I call subscribeOn(Schedulers.IO) to do the calculations. And I can't understand why is it happening. Am I get it clear, that I should call subscribeOn(io) to do the calculation and represent the result using observeOn(UI) ?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the anwer is - when you are working with UI element (not server call) - you should subscribe on the UI thread and the opposite one with server call?

Comment: "First, specify that code down the chain should start on the main thread instead of on the I/O thread. In Android, all code that works with Views should execute on the main thread." - this I've took from the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is a little misleading because of the .map operator, which is actually used to perform an expensive operation (search). A better way to do it would be to wrap the code with fromCallable and convert it to an async call with subscribeOn. Something like that:

```
searchTextObservable
            // Means start a new async search every time text is changed
            .flatMapSingle { Single
                .fromCallable { cheeseSearchEngine.search(it) }
                // This makes sure search is running on IO thread
                // This way expensive operation is done off the main thread, which eliminates the freeze
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) }
            // This makes sure that results will be handled on main thread
            // Important because you can only access Android Widgets from the main thread
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                showResult(it)
            }
```

The explanationas are in Code. I think the intent is much clearer now. For details see the answer by HansWursrt